# 0 en las fechas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hay alguna forma de que MySQL escriba el 0 delante cuando los números son menores de 10 ? En este caso ocurre en los segundos (pone 4 en vez de 04), pero me gustaria tambien poder controlarlo en los minutos y en la hora

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(fn_diabreviado (DAYNAME(fecha_inicio)),' ', HOUR(fecha_inicio),':',MINUTE(fecha_inicio),':',SECOND(fecha_inicio),'-',HOUR(fecha_fin),':',MINUTE(fecha_fin),':',SECOND(fecha_fin)) AS fecha FROM conexiones.registro_actual WHERE ID_equipo=(SELECT ID FROM equipos WHERE hostname='W7-1') ;

+--------------------+

| fecha              |

+--------------------+

| T 20:24:4-21:23:54 |

+--------------------+

1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Gracias por la ayuda :)

---

Mis tablas:

```sql
mysql> DESCRIBE equipos;

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| ID       | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| hostname | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

| ip       | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

3 rows in set (0,00 sec)



mysql> DESCRIBE registro_actual;

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

| Field        | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

| ID           | int       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |

| ID_equipo    | int       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |

| fecha_inicio | timestamp | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |

| fecha_fin    | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Prueba a darle formato a cada numero de la siguiente manera: `format(num,'00')`

Comment: Ok. Pero no entiendo muy bien como pondria eso en la consulta

Comment: La pregunta real es, porque quieres que la BD haga esto. Devuelve el campo `fecha_inicio` tal cual está en BD y dale el formato correspondiente en tu aplicación, probablemente en la interfaz de usuario.

Comment: No necesitas nada de esto, ni siquiera el `CONCAT`, puedes formatear una fecha usando `DATE_FORMAT`, [revisa el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: Ok. Lo de DATE_FORMAT no lo sabia, pero necesito este formato así porque es para usar un script que cree las acls en squid proxy. Y la sintaxis de squid es dia de la semana con una letra y luego fecha inicio - fecha fin, y necesito esos ceros en la fecha sí o sí para que esté bien configurado el proxy

Comment: ¿La `T` que es, `Tuesday`? Puedes hacerlo todo con `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: La T es tuesday sí, Y lo de poner 04 en vez de 4 también lo puedo hacer con DATE_FORMAT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) del siguiente modo (pongo sólo la parte relevante, adáptala en tu código):

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%a'), 1, 1), ' ', 
DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%H:%i:%s'),
        '-',
        DATE_FORMAT(fecha_fin, '%H:%i:%s')
    ) AS fechas 
FROM registro_actual;
```

La salida será algo como esto:

> ```
> | fechas              |
> | :------------------ |
> | W 15:45:59-20:10:00 |
> | W 15:46:01-20:10:00 |
> ```

---

Aquí te dejo un fiddle completo:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE registro_actual (
>   ID  MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>   fecha_inicio TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   fecha_fin TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '2022-05-11 20:10:00'
>
>   
> );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO registro_actual (ID) values (null);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> DO SLEEP(2);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO registro_actual (ID) values (null);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from registro_actual;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | fecha_inicio        | fecha_fin          
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------
>  1 | 2022-05-11 15:45:59 | 2022-05-11 20:10:00
>  2 | 2022-05-11 15:46:01 | 2022-05-11 20:10:00
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     CONCAT(
>         SUBSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%a'), 1, 1), ' ', 
> DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%H:%i:%s'),
>         '-',
>         DATE_FORMAT(fecha_fin, '%H:%i:%s')
>     ) AS fechas 
> FROM registro_actual;
> ```
>
> ```
> | fechas              |
> | :------------------ |
> | W 15:45:59-20:10:00 |
> | W 15:46:01-20:10:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25bf615e3af8fecc54001d6849344577)*

Comment: Gracias. Era justo lo que queria